# MongoDb Sink Connector :: JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'dist'

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to establish a data flow wherein a mosquitto publisher will send data to the kafka broker via MQTT Source Connector and the kafka broker will forward the input data to a MongoDb database via MonoDb Sink Connector. The MQTT Source Connector and MongoDb Source Connector are individually working properly. When I'm trying to integrate both the connectors it is giving me an exception. I've spent loads of hours in finding the solution and have failed in doing so. I need help in establishing this data flow.

**mqttPublisher.py**

```
data = {
         "time": str(datetime.datetime.now().time()),
          "val": 0
        }

client.publish("dist", json.dumps(data), qos=2)
```

**kafkaConsumer.py**

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('mqtt.',
                       bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
for msg in consumer:
    print(msg)
```

**source-anonymous.properties**

```
name=MQTT-source
tasks.max=1
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceConnector
mqtt.server.uri=tcp://127.0.0.1:1883
mqtt.topics=dist
kafka.topics=mqtt.
```

**MongoDbSinkConnector.properties**

```
name=MyMongoDbSinkConnector
topics=mqtt.
tasks.max=1

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
connector.class=at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkConnector


mongodb.connection.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/sample?w=1&journal=true
mongodb.collection=data
mongodb.max.num.retries=3
mongodb.retries.defer.timeout=5000

mongodb.document.id.strategy =at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.processor.id.strategy.BsonOidStrategy


mongodb.post.processor.chain =at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.processor.DocumentIdAdder

mongodb.delete.on.null.values=false


mongodb.writemodel.strategy =at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneDefaultStrategy
mongodb.max.batch.size=0
```

**Output (kafkaConsumer.py)**

```
ConsumerRecord(topic='mqtt.', partition=0, offset=0, timestamp=1545759406558, timestamp_type=0, key=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x08dist', value=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02J{"time": "23:06:46.548284", "val": 0}', headers=[('mqtt.message.id', b'0'), ('mqtt.qos', b'0'), ('mqtt.retained', b'false'), ('mqtt.duplicate', b'false')], checksum=None, serialized_key_size=10, serialized_value_size=43, serialized_header_size=62)
```

**CLI command for starting Connectors:**

```
bin/connect-standalone etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-mqtt/etc/source-anonymous.properties share/confluent-hub-components/hpgrahsl-kafka-connect-mongodb/etc/MongoDbSinkConnector.properties
```

**Logs**

```
[2018-12-25 23:07:52,280] INFO Created connector MQTT-source (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:104)
[2018-12-25 23:07:52,346] INFO Connecting to Mqtt Server. (io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceTask:67)
[2018-12-25 23:07:52,371] INFO Subscribing to dist with QOS of 0 (io.confluent.connect.mqtt.MqttSourceTask:76)
[2018-12-25 23:07:52,380] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=MQTT-source-0} Source task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:199)
.
.
.
.
[2018-12-25 23:07:52,615] INFO Creating connector MyMongoDbSinkConnector of type at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:235)
[2018-12-25 23:07:52,616] INFO Instantiated connector MyMongoDbSinkConnector with version 1.2.0 of type class at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:238)
[2018-12-25 23:07:52,616] INFO Finished creating connector MyMongoDbSinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:257)
.
.
.
[2018-12-25 23:07:52,706] INFO Created connector MyMongoDbSinkConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:104)
[2018-12-25 23:07:52,708] INFO starting MongoDB sink task (at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkTask:78)
.
.
[2018-12-25 23:07:52,943] INFO Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500} (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:71)
[2018-12-25 23:07:53,013] INFO WorkerSinkTask{id=MyMongoDbSinkConnector-0} Sink task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:302)
[2018-12-25 23:07:53,037] INFO Cluster ID: VX_AdknXRGGfEWsSdcSpSw (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata:285)
[2018-12-25 23:07:53,057] INFO Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:14}] to localhost:27017 (org.mongodb.driver.connection:71)
[2018-12-25 23:07:53,063] INFO Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 6, 4]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=6, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=3937492} (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:71)
[2018-12-25 23:07:53,869] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-MyMongoDbSinkConnector] Discovered group coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:677)
[2018-12-25 23:07:53,871] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-MyMongoDbSinkConnector] Revoking previously assigned partitions [] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:472)
[2018-12-25 23:07:53,871] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-MyMongoDbSinkConnector] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:509)
[2018-12-25 23:07:53,976] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-MyMongoDbSinkConnector] Successfully joined group with generation 1 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:473)
[2018-12-25 23:07:53,980] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-MyMongoDbSinkConnector] Setting newly assigned partitions [mqtt.-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:280)
[2018-12-25 23:07:53,991] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=connect-MyMongoDbSinkConnector] Resetting offset for partition mqtt.-0 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher:583)
[2018-12-25 23:07:54,189] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=MyMongoDbSinkConnector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. 
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:584)
    org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'dist'.
    at org.bson.json.JsonReader.readBsonType(JsonReader.java:251)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:680)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:722)
    at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:450)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:81)
    at org.bson.BsonDocument.parse(BsonDocument.java:62)
    at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.converter.JsonRawStringRecordConverter.convert(JsonRawStringRecordConverter.java:32)
    at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.converter.SinkConverter.convert(SinkConverter.java:44)
    at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkTask.lambda$buildWriteModel$3(MongoDbSinkTask.java:186)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkTask.buildWriteModel(MongoDbSinkTask.java:185)
    at  at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkTask.processSinkRecords(MongoDbSinkTask.java:122)
    .
    .
```

MongoDb Sink Connector : https://github.com/hpgrahsl/kafka-connect-mongodb

Kafka-Connect MQTT Source Connector Demo : https://github.com/kaiwaehner/kafka-connect-iot-mqtt-connector-example/blob/master/live-demo-kafka-connect-iot-mqtt-connector.adoc

**UPDATE:**

Following is the output I'm getting on the kafka-avro-console-consumer:

```
"dist"  "J{\"time\": \"23:06:46.548284\", \"val\": 0}"
```

cli command used :

```
bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic mqtt. --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property print.key=true
```

Schema registered on the schema-registry:

```
{"subject":"mqtt.-key","version":1,"id":1,"schema":"\"string\""}
{"subject":"mqtt.-value","version":1,"id":2,"schema":"\"bytes\""}
```

command used to fetch schemas :

```
curl --silent -X GET http://localhost:8081/subjects/mqtt.-[key|value]/versions/latest
```

Comment: I suggest trying the console sink connector to debug. But the issue appears to be with the Mongo connector. For example, are you supposed to be using `BsonOidStrategy`?

Comment: The Mongo sink connector is working properly when I am sending data from a kafka Producer, but here with mosquitto_publisher its giving Exceptions. 
I am using the default BsonOidStrategy as we can't keep it empty.

Comment: And the "working" version is using Avro for keys and values? My point was only that the stacktrace starts with `BsonDocument.parse`, so some Bson data is getting generated incorrectly

Comment: yep I'm using Avro key-value converters

Comment: `"J{\"time\": \"23:06:46.548284\", \"val\": 0}"` is a raw string, and the schema registry says that value just bytes, not an Avro record... So, I don't think the AvroConverter is going to work for that record

Comment: In the output of **kafkaConsumer.py**, the key and value have 5 bytes prepended which comply with the [wire format](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/serializer-formatter.html#wire-format) used for avro messages . What do you recommend should I do to make this work ? Is this happening due to incorrect schemas,converters or something else ?

Comment: Well, you should be [using AvroConsumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/README.md#usage), but I'm talking about the avro console consumer, not your Python code or its output... All I'm saying is that the value is clearly just bytes or a string, not a nested record of key-values for "time" and "val". If it were, then the schema registry would say so, not just "bytes"

Comment: I changed the converters being used and used an [SMT](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/extracttopic.html) that solved my problem

Comment: Feel free to add your complete answer below

Comment: Please don't use a commnet. Use the answer box below.

Answer (score 0):

So This worked for me:

1. Added this SMT to **source-anonymous.properties**
   `transforms=requiredKeyExample`   `transforms.requiredKeyExample.type=io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Key`
2. Changed key-value converters in **connect-standalone.properties** as : `key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` `value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter`
3. Changed key-value converters in **MongoDbSinkConnector.properties** as : `key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` `value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`